# Generate a large file in memory and stream it into object store

Tags: python

I'm trying to do some load testing of an openstack swift object store and want to see transfer and fail rates of large files. How can I generate a big file of 0s and stream it somewhere as its generated?

In bash I would do something like

```
dd if=/dev/zero | aws s3 cp - s3://destination/thing
```

Example of reading a file from disk

```
with open("test.png", "rb") as f:
  client.put_object("default", "photos/my_copy_of_test.png", f.read())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`put_object`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) method requires either `bytes` or a file object.

In your existing code, for some reason, you're passing `f.read()` instead of `f`, meaning you're reading the whole file into memory and then passing the bytes. If that's acceptable with file data, surely it's acceptable with in-memory data, so you can just build a big `bytes` and pass that.

If you don't want to build the whole buffer in advance, what you need to do is create a file object that generates bytes on demand whenever the consumer calls one of the `read` functions.

In Python 3, the way to do that is to create a class that implements either `io.RawIOBase` or `io.BufferedIOBase`. As you can see from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy), to do this, you only need to supply a couple of methods, and the rest get automatically generated for you.

---

Raw I/O is simpler. The main method you need to write is [`readinto`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.readinto). You will be passed a `bytearray` (or other mutable `bytes`-like object), and expected to fill in as much of it as possible. So, your class could look like this:

```
class StreamingFile(io.RawIOBase):
    def readinto(self, b):
        buf = generate_raw_bytes(len(b))
        b[:len(buf)] = buf
        return len(buf)
```

(Obviously if you can write that `generate_raw_bytes` function to generate the data directly in `b` instead of copying it over, it will be more efficient.)

The `put_object` method is probably actually going to call some other file method, like `read`, `readline`, readlines`,`**iter**`, etc., but that's fine;`RawIOBase`automatically gives you implementations of all of those methods in terms of your`readinto`.

---

What if you can't control exactly how many bytes you generate; you can only create a line at a time, and that could be anywhere from 1 byte to 300, even if you were only asked for 40? Then you want to use an internal buffer. You can still do that with `RawIOBase`, but it's probably better to implement `BufferedIOBase` instead, and define the [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read) and [`read1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read) methods.